# Angular 6 MatDialog cancel close event

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular6

I have two components: `CustomerComponent` and `CustomerCreateUpdateComponent`.

`CustomerComponent` includes data table of customers.
`CustomerCreateUpdateComponent` is a form with input controls for create/update.

I have `mat-dialog` with `CustomerCreateUpdateComponent` in it.
After opening the dialog and filling the form, I click submit button and `this.dialogRef.close(customer);` is executed. `customer` object has all values.

In `CustomerComponent` I've `subscribe` on `this.dialog.open(CustomerCreateUpdateComponent).beforeClose().subscribe((customer: Customer) => { ... });`

It's `beforeClose()` method, so until the dialog is closed, I get back `customer` object back and POST it to api.

If POST is successful everything is OK, the dialog is closed and data table updated.

BUT, if POST did not succeed, api will return an error, which I want to show to the user and **KEEP THE DIALOG OPEN**, something like `if(error) { closeEvent.cancel() }`

I've seen the whole documentation for `mat-dialog`, nothing helpful. I'm almost sure there is not way to do it.

Maybe someone had the same issue? Will be glad to hear any workaround.

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar issue because I wanted a confirm-close warning to pop up before closing, and then to cancel or delay the close until it was confirmed. To handle this, I set the `disableClose` option to true on the dialog. I added my close method hook to the backdropClick hook so that it behaved in a similar way.

```js
this.dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => { this.close(); });
```

`close()` is my method for handling close events on the dialog. That simply opens a confirmation box and closes if the answer is yes

```js
close() {
    this.confirm.open({ title: 'Would you like to acknowledge this message?' }).pipe(
      tap(answer => { if (answer === true) { this.dialogRef.close(); } }),
    ).subscribe();
}
```

Adding a cancel callback to the close hooks is only a convenience which is probably why they haven't done it right already.

Comment: The best solution in my opinion and not a hack!

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same trouble, and find some 'solution'. As I understood you can't prevent the close event of the dialog so I tried to find some alternative way.

Firstly, I have removed `[mat-dialog-close]="..." cdkFocusInitial` from the call of OK button like this.

```html
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onCancelClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="clickOn()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

after it, I have passed that `service` object to the component of the dialog, and make that POST call from the component of the dialog, and if all is OK now I am call `dialogRef.close(...callbackResull...)` otherwise I don't close dialogRef and do all that I need in Dialog-component, as a result I have.

```js
    clickOn() {
        <Your POST call which returns observable>.subscribe(() => {
              this.dialogRef.close(this.selfRequest);
            },
            error1 => {
              // Do here what you need
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is similar as I resolved. I'm calling POST request in `CustomerCreateUpdateComponent`. If everything is OK, then I call `this.dialogRef.close` event or giving error message to user.

But I think it would be nice, if `this.dialog.open(CustomerCreateUpdateComponent).beforeClose().subscribe` method had something like `event.cancel`

Comment: Completely agree with you!

Answer (score -5):

```
this.dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(
  () => (this.isDialogOpen = false)
);
```

Comment: Please give at least some description why this answers the question.